# Mail getting blocked as abuse, error 500

Tags: email, blacklist

we just moved our domain ( daytonaparts.com ) to a new service provider ( ait.net ) and since we went live we have had our emails rejected by AT&T and Microsoft ( Hotmail, MSN, Live.com ) with an Error 500 based on our IP. We are not sending spam or newsletters, these are just responses to customer emails. We have tried to contact the 2 behemoths but have gotten nowhere.
Does anyone have any Ideas how to get removed from these lists

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is use a service like mailgun or sendgrid. They provide a way to relay your email through their email servers like its coming from you. Both offer free tiers that allow you to send like 10k emails a month.

Once setup, you never have to worry about keeping your ip range off a blacklist.